# How do you use solve.QP in R using quadprog for investment portfolio optimization with no short sales

Tags: r

In R, using quadprog, in the function solve.QP for investment portfolio optimization, how do you set the constraint for the sum of the weights to equal one, and every weight is non-negative, (no short sales)?

Comment: There is also a wrapper for this in the `tseries` package.

Answer (score 4):

Let `V` be the variance matrix of the asset returns,
`mu` their expected returns,
and `n` the number of assets.
The following finds `w` that minimizes 
`t(w) %*% V %*% w - mu`
subject to the constraints 
`sum(w)=1` and `w>=0`.

```
library(quadprog)
A <- cbind(                 # One constraint per column
  matrix( rep(1,n), nr=n ), # The weights sum up to 1
  diag(n)                   # No short-selling
)
b <- c(1, rep(0,n))
r <- solve.QP(V, mu, A, b, meq=1)
```

Comment: According to the Documentation, your code minimizes 1/2*t(w) %*% V %*% w - mu. This is probably not a big thing, however, if someone is interested in getting so-called efficient portfolios, scaling matters due to different risk aversion factors.